# How to call a function from a php file?

Tags: php

So I have this function `register_user` in a php file called `functions`, this function has been used to activate user who register on my website.

```
function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'sanitise_array');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mock_exam_users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
    email($register_data['email_address'], 'Activate your account', "Hello " . $register_data['first_name'] .",\n\nTo activate your account, click on the link below or copy and paste the URL on to your browser.\nhttp://7ea8d47c.ngrok.io/mocktime/activate.php?email=" . $register_data['email_address'] . "&email_code=" . $register_data['email_code'] ." \n\nmockTime");
}
```

Within my login page where I check for validations when user logins, one of my check is to check if the user has activated their email.

```
if (user_active($email_address) === false) {

    $errors[] = 'Email Address is not activated !';
}
```

I would like to know if there is anyway I could pass in the `register_user` function within this if statement as an alternative way of re-sending the email.

I hope I described the problem in good detail, however if you guys need any more details please message.

Comment: Do you know about the `require` statement in PHP? That's how you load functions from one file into another file.

Answer (score 1):

First include functions.php file and then call register_user function with parameters:

Include("functions.php");
register_user(data);

Comment: Hi I know how to call "<?php include 'core/functions.php'; ?>", But I am not fully sure how to call register_user(data) ????

Comment: Because register_user passes a parameter which I don't have access when I do this if condition to see if the user's email address is activated

Answer (score 1):

Short-answer:

```
require_once('file_containing_registered_user.php');
```

Comment: I prefer require_once over include as PHP will check if the file has already been included,